# iOS Viewing Multipage tiff images

Tags: ios, tiff, multipage

I would like to know is there a way to view multi page tiff files in iOS (iPad) without using any third party apps?

What we have today - We asked our users to download Multiple page image viewer app
however our end users are requesting us to provide an ability to view multi page tiff without installing the third party paps